# What is the best way to Deserialize an object from json to a class?

Tags: c#, json, object, httpclient

I am implementing a system for GPS Tracking, through the consumption of a web service api.

ERROR :

> An unhandled exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.dll
>
> Additional information: Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'TrackingRequest.Devices' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.
>
> To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.

This is in a web form application in c# with `HttpClient` using json of Newtonsoft.

My code

```
using (HttpClient clientKey = new HttpClient())
                   {
                        clientKey.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://api.trackingdiary.com/");
                        clientKey.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Hive-Session", key);
                        clientKey.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                        HttpResponseMessage responseKey = clientKey.GetAsync("/v2/geo/devices/list").Result;
                        using (HttpContent contentkey = responseKey.Content)
                       {
                            Task<string> resultKey = contentkey.ReadAsStringAsync();
                            Devices obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Devices>(resultKey.Result);

                           Console.WriteLine();
                       }
                   }
```

My Class:

```
    class position
    {
        [JsonProperty("lat")]
        public int lat { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("lng")]
        public int lng { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("hdop")]
        public int hdop { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("fix")]
        public bool fix { get; set; }
    }

    class Devices
    {
        [JsonProperty("id")]
        public int id { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("name")]
        public string name { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("date_contacted")]
        public string date_contacted { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("startup")]
        public string startup { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("position")]
        public position position { get; set; }    
    }
}
```

I want in objects to perform in DataTable.

JSON EXAMPLE
[JSON EXAMPLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Or5YD.png)

Comment: Can you show an example `json` response you are working with please?

Comment: C# convention says that your properties should be PascalCased: `Id`, `Name`, `DateContacted` etc. They don't need to match the incoming JSON, that's handled by the `[JsonProperty("date_contacted")]`

Comment: Without seing the JSON it's hard to be sure but the error message seems pretty clear : you're trying to turn an array into an object.

Comment: @TobySmith ThisIsPascalCaseNotCamelCase butThisIsCamelCase.

Comment: the Json returned is a list of devices not a single device object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your JSON string contains an array of objects of the type in question. You are trying to deserialize it into a single instance, hence the error.

Try this:

```
IEnumerable<Devices> devices = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<Devices>>(resultKey.Result);
```

And please rename the class to singular since it appears to represent a single `Device`.

Comment: This might be the answer now, but since OP hasn't given enough information we cannot tell. Should really have waited for concrete information.

Comment: @DavidG. True. Although the error is very suggestive, It's impossible to tell without seeing the actual payload.For all you know, he could be receiving a completely different [serialized] type, LOL...

Comment: It Works.Thanks a lot for very fast solution.